# how to make only one switch button enabled

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three switch buttons in my form and I want that user can switch on one button and others became automatically off. I do not want to use typical radio button in my form. I get switch button from : http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

my html is :

```
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

and my css is :

```
<style type="text/css">
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Also I want to switch on "Buy" default button

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: i dont have javascript

Comment: You need js to achieve the behavior that what you want.

Comment: do you have any solution??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use radio instead of checkbox and add "checked" for default option

```
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" checked>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="radio" name="switch">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tu25Lr8t/

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following change event

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !this.checked); //toggle the state of the current checkbox
  $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false); // uncheck  all checkboxes except the current one 
});
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}
/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can disabled other checkboxes, change accordingly in your code.

You just get the current clicked checkbox and then disable all other checkboxes by using `.not()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(":checkbox").not($(this)).attr("disabled","disabled");
      //$(":checkbox").not($(this)).prop("disabled",true);
    }
    else{
      $(":checkbox").not($(this)).removeAttr("disabled");
      //$(":checkbox").not($(this)).prop("disabled",false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" /> Button 1
<input type="checkbox" /> Button 2
<input type="checkbox" /> Button 3
```